# Android Studio: How do I get my cursor to also pull the primary key?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I had this block of code/method provided for me which puts data into a recycler view, but it doesn't pull the primary key from what I noticed. How can I edit it so it also pulls the primary key?

Here is the block/method:

```
    public ArrayList<String[]> getData(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int columns = cursor.getColumnCount();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (columns == 3) {
                    // a regular row
                    long[] fields = new long[3];
                    fields[0] = cursor.getLong(0);
                    fields[1] = cursor.getLong(1);
                    fields[2] = cursor.getLong(2);

                    data.add(new String[]{TimeUtils.timeToDate(fields[0]),
                            Long.toString(fields[1]),
                            Long.toString(fields[2])});
                } else if (columns == 2) {
                    // An average value
                    double field1 = cursor.getDouble(0);
                    double field2 = cursor.getDouble(1);
                    data.add(new String[]{"-",
                            String.format("%.2f", field1),
                            String.format("%.2f", field2)});
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Does the SELECT statement that produces the cursor include the primary key, and what is the primary key column name?

Comment: You just solved it for me lol. In the example provided it did not, but in the app I'm making it does. I just have to edit this to match it. Thanks!